# Нужно перенести данный скрипт с VBA на php

Tags: php, excel, vba, imacros

Для моего проекта нужно перенести данный код на php, помогите пожалуйста.

```
Function A00(x)
alp = "0123456789AEXKMHPCT"
c = posc(x Mod 19 ^ 6, 6)
For q = 1 To 6
c0 = InStr(alp, Mid(c, q, 1)) - 1
j = (j + (q * 2 - 1) * c0) Mod 19
Select Case q
  Case 1, 4: c = Left(c, q - 1) + Mid(alp, 19 - c0, 1) + Right(c, 6 - q)
End Select
Next q
A00 = Left(c, 3) + "-" + Mid(c, 4, 1) + Mid(alp, j + 1, 1) + Right(c, 2)
End Function
```

Буду признателен за любую помощь, особенно интересует строка `c = posc(x Mod 19 ^ 6, 6)`, что она делает?

Comment: Сами начните переносить и напишите то что не получается вместе с частично написанным решением. У нас не сайт фриланса, где за вас всё сделают по вашему повелению :)

Comment: @DanielProtopopov, я смогу перенести без проблем, вопрос заключается именно в том, что делает строка  c = posc(x Mod 19 ^ 6, 6). Конкретно функция posc(). Нагуглить это не получилось

Comment: Видимо эта функция находится в каком-то модуле, ибо в [списках](https://bettersolutions.com/vba/functions/complete-list.htm) [встроенных функций](https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/index_vba.php) её нет.